# Timing of events when the mouse moves through overlapping or nested areas

Tags: javascript, events, timing, onmouseover, onmouseout

When I have nested objects, the timing of events that occur when a mouse passes though is very counterintuitive and complex. Can someone explain the rules for the timing?

For example, when I have nested `div`s like the following:

[image: nested div]

where each div has the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` properties so that they fire events, they do so in the following order:

- When the mouse moves 1 --> 2

  > mouseover 2
- When the mouse moves 2 --> 3

  > mouseout 2
  >   mouseover 3
  >   mouseover 2
- When the mouse moves 3 --> 4

  > mouseout 3
  >   mouseout 2
  >   mouseover 4
  >   mouseover 2
  >   mouseover 3
- When the mouse moves 4 --> 5

  > mouseout 2
  >   mouseover 5
  >   mouseout 3
  >   mouseover 4
  >   mouseout 4
  >   mouseover 3
  >   mouseover 2
- When the mouse moves 5 --> 4

  > mouseout 5
  >   mouseout 4
  >   mouseover 3
  >   mouseover 4
  >   mouseout 2
  >   mouseout 3
  >   mouseover 2
- When the mouse moves 4 --> 3

  > mouseout 4
  >   mouseover 3
  >   mouseover 2
  >   mouseout 3
  >   mouseout 2
- When the mouse moves 3 --> 2

  > mouseout 3
  >   mouseout 2
  >   mouseover 2
- When the mouse moves 2 --> 1

  > mouseout 2

I am particularly using Firefox 9.0. Please let me know if there is difference between webbrowsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend you to use [mouseenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mouseenter) and [mouseleave](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mouseleave) events. Mouseover and mouseout are tricky when using nested elements.
From docs:

> Similar to mouseover , it differs in that it doesn't [bubble](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.bubbles) and that
>   it isn't sent until the pointer has moved from its physical space and
>   the one of all its descendants.

Also I recommend using and I use most of times [jQuery Hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) helper which binds those non-buggy-bubbling events.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I tried, but mouseenter and mouseleave do not seem to be supperted until Firefox 10. I hope it becomes available soon.

Comment: jQuery hover seems to be the answer in the meanwhile. Thank you.

Comment: Sawa, you're right mouseenter is IE only. I'm too attached to jQuery. But there is a hack at http://blog.stchur.com/2007/03/15/mouseenter-and-mouseleave-events-for-firefox-and-other-non-ie-browsers/ basically it does ignore the mouseover event if it was triggered from an inside element

Comment: Thanks for the link to the hack.